# Fill table with a lot of data using UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-update

I have a main table with a lot of data, lets say for example:

```
Name    Status   LastVisit     Department    ReportDate
John    lost     June          Main          August
Johny   lost     May           Main          August
Johnie  Active   August        Main          August
Johnes  lost     June          Secondary     August
Johneb  lost     May           Secondary     August
Johna   Active   August        Secondary     August
```

Above is an example of a table  1 .

Now for this table I wnat to create a summary table that just gives me specific stuff, for sakes of simplicity, IdleClient means that DATEDIFF(Month) between ReportDate and LastVisit is 1 or greater.

```
IdleClient  ActiveClient  LostClient   Department   ReportDate
   2             1            2          Main         August
   2             1            2          Main         August
```

I have a formula that does an Insert Into which does what I want above,  however my issue is with Update , as the syntax is different.

This is what I have for my insert into:

```
INSERT INTO [Table2]([Department],[ReportDate],[IdleClient])
SELECT [Department],[ReportDate],COUNT([Name])
FROM Table1
WHERE 
DATEDIFF(month, dbo.Table1.[LastVisit],dbo.Table1.[ReportDate]) > 0
group by [ReportDate],[Department]
```

my table 2 is just a summary with some counts with conditions like the one above, there is of course more conditions but I want to build the rest of it my self and just need a bit of help in regards with the Syntax of the UPDATE statement.

edit: my insert into is fine, my issue is how do I conver that insert into to a UPDATE.

ReportDate and Last Visit are in the format : YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Are you really storing dates as month names?

Comment: No, is just as a sample , Dates are stored as YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: OK, then you should edit your question to show the relevant data. Manipulating month names would make the query much harder to write.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the department on the second row of the resultset be `Secondary` instead of `Main`?

Comment: True, but the SELECT INTO still works fine.  I jus thave no idea how to make it into an UPDATE as I need to update the rows on table2, not insert new rows into it .

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation. If your dates are stored as *dates*, this will do it:

```
select 
    sum(case when datediff(month, LastVisit, ReportDate) > 1 then 1 else 0 end) IdleClient,
    sum(case when Status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end) ActiveClient,
    sum(case when Status = 'lost' then 1 else 0 end) LostClient,
    Department
from Table1
group by Department
```

You can turn this to an `update` query:

```
update t2
set 
    t2.IdleClient = t1.IdleClient, 
    t2.ActiveClient = t1.ActiveClient, 
    t2.LostClient = t1.LostClient
from Table2 t2
inner join (
    select 
        sum(case when datediff(month, LastVisit, ReportDate) > 1 then 1 else 0 end) IdleClient,
        sum(case when Status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end) ActiveClient,
        sum(case when Status = 'lost' then 1 else 0 end) LostClient,
        Department
    from Table1
    group by Department
) t1 on t1.Department = t2.Department
```

Comment: I like this idea, yet my issue is using this in a UPDATE instead of select into. my select into does what  I need it to do, but I need to instead of add more rows to table 2, just update the existing rows with new data.

Comment: @VictorJMytre: I am lost. Do you want an `insert`, an `update` or an `insert`? And in which table?

Comment: I want an Update, that does what the INSERT INTO does tha ti have.

Basically be able to fill what I show on table 2 from table 1 using an UPDATE

Comment: @VictorJMytre: OK, I edited my answer with an `UPDATE ... JOIN ...` query for that purpose.

Comment: quick question, about the first set , t1 does ont hav an idleclient,activeclient or lostclient .  Or maybe  I dont understand why you put that set at first.

Comment: @VictorJMytre: in the scope of the outer query, `t1` is an alias that refers to the derived table generated by the aggregate subquery. So `t1  does not relate to `Table1` but to the result of the `group by` subquery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206028/discussion-between-victor-j-mytre-and-gmb).